# Select entire function call or extend selection

Tags: visual-mode, functions, selection

I have the following situation a lot, where I always end up having to yank two things in a row: For example, I want to yank a function call:

```
func(a, b)
```

Okay, here I can go to `f` and press `vf)`.

But when the call is nested, this does not work anymore:

```
func(gunk(a), b)
```

Here I always end up going to for example `b`, doing `da(`, then move to where I want to paste it, then move back to `func`, do `diw` and move AGAIN to where I pasted `(gunk(a), b)`.

Instead, I would like to do `vi(` to select `(gunk(a), b)` and then somehow extend the selection to the left by one word, so and up with the complete `func(gunk(a), b)` as the selection.

Is there a way to do that which does not involve writing a custom function to add to the .vimrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For

```
func(gunk(a, b))
```

with the cursor on the `f` of `func`, I would press `y%` or `d%`. The `%` command jumps between matching pairs (roughly; depending on configuration, optional plugins that ship with Vim, etc.), but it also *first* finds an opening pair if not already on one. That means `v%` in this situation covers all of `func(gunk(a, b))`, as desired, and `y%` or `d%` yanks or deletes the desired text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
vf(%`
```

`f(` moves the the first parenthesis

`%` moves to the matching parenthesis

Another way if your are at `b` and to follow your idea is:

```
va(ob
```

`va(` select `(gunc(a, b))`

`o` switch the cursor in front od the selection

`b` extend it to `func(gunc(a, b))`

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks.

Comment: `vabob` is enough, not sure why `bw`, and the first line looks a bit odd (v Space? f(%`?)